# Sublime C++ namespace keyword color scheming

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I am having an annoying behavior in Sublime.

When I start typing out the line...

```
using namespace SomeNamespace;
```

The keywords 'using' and 'namespace' are properly colored the keyword coloring. Then when I add the semicolon to the end of the line, the namespace keyword goes white (default text color). I know this is not that significant, but it really annoys me.

Has anyone noticed this behavior before? The code compiles without errors or warnings, so I know sublime is not detecting some so of code problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: the namespace keyword is not colored the designated keyword color. Once I add the semi colon, the namespace keyword goes white, instead of having the keyword coloring. But it has the proper coloring before I add the semicolon.

Comment: Oh, I see, I just fired up Sublime and saw it myself. Let me take a look under the hood. In the meantime, a quick before/after screenshot would help.

Comment: What build (version of Sublime) are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this particular regex in the C++ syntax definition:

```
\b(namespace)\s+([A-Za-z_][_A-Za-z0-9:]*\b)?+(?!\s*?(;|=|,))
```

At the very end, in the negative lookahead - `(?!...)` - we see that semicolons are excluded from the match, meaning that if a semicolon is present at the very end of the line, there's no match.

To fix it, you'll need to install the very useful [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin from Package Control. Then, open the Command Palette, type ***`prv`*** to bring up the PackageResourceViewer options, select the **`Extract Package`** one, then scroll down and select **`C++`**. There will now be a `C++` directory in the directory opened by choosing **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**. Go into that directory and you'll see a bunch of files. Depending on what version of Sublime Text 3 you're using, you'll want to open either `C++.tmLanguage` or `C++.sublime-syntax` in Sublime. The `.tmLanguage` format is XML, so you can pick that for syntax highlighting if you wish, while the `.sublime-syntax` file is in YAML.

Once the appropriate file is open (you'll either have one or the other, not both), search for the regex above, or just search for `namespace`, you should find it pretty easily. Delete the `;|` from near the end, making the whole thing:

```
\b(namespace)\s+([A-Za-z_][_A-Za-z0-9:]*\b)?+(?!\s*?(=|,))
```

Save the file, and that's it! Your C++ source files should update their behavior immediately - if not, just close and reopen them, and in the worst case you can just close them, restart Sublime, then reopen them.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks.